# How to add help text to tabs in admin/structure/types/manage/{node-type}

Tags: 7, forms

I maintain a module (http://www.drupal.org/project/csm) that adds two tabs to the node type settings form at admin/structure/types/manage/{node-type}. I'd like to add some help text to these tabs. In the picture below, there is help text set for the top four tabs, but not for the last three tabs.

[image: Screenshot of node type settings page]

I've had a look at the Drupal core code to see if I can work out how to set this help text, but have had no joy so far. How can I set it?

For the record, the code used to generate the last tab in the form is as follows:

```
$form['cnpt'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Node creation page title and status message'),
  '#access' => user_access('change ' . $form['#node_type']->type . ' creation page title'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  '#group' => 'additional_settings',
  //'#tree' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => 101,
  '#attributes' => array('class' => array('csm-form')),
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summaries are dynamic so they're controlled by JS. It should be something as simple as this:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.csmFieldsetSummaries = {
    attach: function (context) {
      $('fieldset.csm-form', context).drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
        // Make a decision about what summary to display based on your tab's current value.
        var summary = $('input.foo', context).is(':checked') ? 'Input checked' : 'Input not checked';      

        // Or static strings are fine too.
        summary = 'Static summary';

        return Drupal.t(summary);
      });

      $('fieldset.another-csm-form', context).drupalSetSummary(function (context) {
        // ...
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Superb, thank you so much! I should add, for anyone who finds this useful, that I also had to add '#attached' => array('js'=>array(drupal_get_path('module', 'csm') . '/csm.js'),), to $form['cnpt'] so the form went off to find csm.js (where I put the JS you've written) :)